# Floating point of fixed point division using Shift Operator in Verilog HDL

Tags: floating-point, division, bit-shift, multiplication, fixed-point

I want to ask if it is possible to divide the floating-point or fixed number using the shift operators. I want to divide the floating-point or fixed number in the power of 2? I know for decimal numbers we can use shift operators in Verilog HDL for division and multiplication.

Comment: Ignoring overflow/underflow problems you can divide by a power of two, by subtracting that number from the exponent part. For binary fixed point numbers you can do ordinary shifting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to divide (bit-shift) a float number, you could use a method called fixed-point.

Say you will (say) hold the number 1.45 (and bit-shift it later). You would store 145 in an integer, and every time you accessed the variable you would divide the value by 2 using shift right operation.

Comment: Saying “If you really want to divide (bit-shift) a float number, you could use a method called fixed-point” is like saying if you really want to drive a car, you could ride a train. “Float,” also known as floating-point, numbers are in a specific kind of format where there is an exponent that makes the decimal or radix point “float.” If you use fixed-point, you are not using floating-point.